# help with query finding multiple entries in 1 column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to query several different colors from one column.  This is what I have so far:

```
=query('Raw Data'!C1:J1000,
"Select E, D, I, J, C, F, H 
  where H contains 'Monday' 
  and F='Green' 
  and C='schools' 
  order by E")
```

For example I want to query all the items that are Green, Red, and Blue in the F column.  Is there a way to query for multiple selection in 1 column?

Answer (score 0):

Two way to do this with a `Query`.

1. With a `regular expression` and `matches` :

   ```
    =query('Raw Data'!C1:J1000,
    "Select E, D, I, J, C, F, H 
      where H contains 'Monday' 
      and F matches 'Red|Green|Blue' 
      and C='schools' 
      order by E")
   ```

> `matches` - A (preg) regular expression match. haystack `matches` needle is true if the regular expression in needle matches haystack.
> **Examples**: `where country matches '.*ia'` matches India and Nigeria, but not Indiana. Note that this is not a global search, so `where country matches 'an'` will not match 'Canada'.

---

[Source : Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where)

2. With classical logic and boolean :

   ```
    =query('Raw Data'!C1:J1000,
    "Select E, D, I, J, C, F, H 
       where H contains 'Monday' 
       and (F='Green' or F='Red' or F='Blue')
       and C='schools' 
       order by E")
   ```

> You can join multiple conditions using the logical operators and, or, and not. Parentheses can be used to define explicit precedence.

[Same source](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where)